# Signing iOS app with other person's credentials

Tags: ios-provisioning

I created an iOS app and client hired a testing firm to test it.
Guys from the firm want me to sign the app with their credentials.

They have sent me 4 files:

- something.p12
- something.cer
- something.mobileprovision
- something.certSigningRequest

What I did is next:

1. imported something.p12 into my keychain
2. imported something.cer into my keychain
3. imported something.mobileprovision into Xcode
4. created a new certificate with my developer account using something.certSigningRequest
5. selected their code signing identity and provisioning profile in Build settings (Xcode)

When I try to archive the app for Ad Hoc Deployment, I get the error:

**No matching provisioning profiles found for “Applications/Something.app”. None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, keychain-access-groups.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like the provisioning profile is not including some entitlements that your app requires, therefore you'd need a new one including them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If by entitlements you mean Capabilities under target options, everything is turned off.
Can the problem exist if provisioning profile is including something that the app doesn’t?

Comment: Are you using a beta of Xcode or a beta of iOS SDK?

Comment: No. I am using Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Can you open the contents of the .mobileprovision file in TextEdit and post them.  I think the bundle ID you are using isn't in the provision profile.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the provisioning profile doesn't support the bundle id in the app you're trying to run / build.  If you open the .mobileprovision file in TextEdit as I said we can probably provide you the answer.

One other thing to note in what you did is that you should not have created a new certificate with their certSigningRequest.  Simply importing their private key (the.p12 file), their certificate (.cer), and provisioning profile (.mobileprovision) should have been enough.

Another thing you can check on is to launch the Keychain Access app, going to Certificates, and verifying that when you click on the iPhone Developer or iPhone Distribution certificate, you see a green check mark with a message in the top pane that says "This certificate is valid" like so:

[image]